# Ruby Inject Weird Behavior

Tags: ruby, arrays, functional-programming, inject

I'm trying to produce the full permutation of a given array. For example, if the input is `fact(2, ['A', 'B'])`, the output should be `[["A", "A"], ["B", "A"], ["A", "B"], ["B", "B"]]`.

```
def fact(n, arr)
    return [[]] if n == 0
    nxt = fact(n - 1, arr).freeze
    arr.inject([]){ |result, elem| nxt.each { |x| result.push(x + [elem]); result } }
end
```

However when I'm trying to do this using a 'more functional programming' way, something weird happened. The interpreter complains `Untitled 4.rb:4:in 'push': can't modify frozen Array (RuntimeError)`. I'm actually trying to modify the injected array named `result`, how could it change `nxt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's built in, and it is lazy:

```
perms = ['A', 'B'].repeated_permutation(2)
#use the resulting enumerator like this:
perms.each{|perm| p perm}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn out to be a typo.

```
def fact(n, arr)
    return [[]] if n == 0
    nxt = fact(n - 1, arr).freeze
    arr.inject([]){ |a, elem| nxt.each { |x| a.push(x + [elem]) }; a }
end
```

Comment: You may want to use `each_with_object` as an alternative to `inject` here as it avoids having to chain `a` forward.